# Is there a way to configure my git repository such that anyone could clone it?

Tags: git

i initialized a bare git repository on my computer in order to share with my local network, but all of the other computers are getting this error message:

> fatal: '//LAPTOP-XXXXXXXX/Users/user/GitServer/repo.git' does not
> appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote
> repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and
> the repository exists.

i tried to initialize it with `--shared=0666` but it also doesn't work.
any ideas?

Comment: Is the path actually accessible via file explorer?

Comment: This isn't really a git question. It's a file sharing question.

Comment: This is not a great idea in general as you are essentially treating your laptop as a server. Instead I'd suggest actually hosting your code somewhere such as Bitbucket, GitLab, etc that you can use to collaborate.

Comment: As @RaymondChen commented this has more to do with how you shared the directory. It would give us a better idea if you added the exact commands/steps you did to create, share the repo, and how you tried to access the directory from another computer.

Comment: Just to rule it out, have someone try the same thing but with a filename that definitely doesn't exist, such as ".../GitServer/blahblah.git" and see if you get the same error message. If you do, this is not a Git question and you need to figure out the network sharing.

Comment: Try to clone yourself with the network path. If you succeed, that's a right problem that you need to solve (not sure it's a good idea to share a repository in its user folder. I think they can access the 'user' folder). If it fails, that's a syntaxe problem you need to solve.